# Understanding a Proof for "A Square Matrix is Invertible If its Rows Are Linearly Independent"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Eric Lengyel's book, *Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics, 3<sup>rd</sup> Edition*, there is a theorem that states

> An $n \times n$ matrix M is invertible if and only if the rows of M form a linearly independent set of vectors.

Two proofs were provided, each corresponding to if and only if of the theorem. I understand the first proof, but I don't fully understand the second one. I have some understanding of it, but it's not enough to fully grasp the proof. The proof, slightly modified for brevity, goes as follows:

> Let the rows of M be denoted by $R_{1}^{T}, R_{2}^{T}, \ldots, R_{n}^{T}$. Now assume that the rows of M are a linearly independent set of vectors. We first observe that performing elementary row operations on a matrix does not alter the property of linear independence within the rows. Running through Algorithm 3.12, if step C fails, then rows *j* through *n* of the matrix at that point form a linearly dependent set since the number of columns for which the rows $R_{j}^{T}$ through $R_{n}^{T}$ have at least one nonzero entry is less than the number of rows itself. This is a contradiction, so step C of the algorithm cannot fail, and M must be invertible.

Note: A screenshot from the book of Algorithm 3.12 is available at the bottom.

What I don't fully understand is this snippet of the proof:

> [...] rows *j* through *n* of the matrix at that point form a linearly dependent set since the number of columns for which the rows $R_{j}^{T}$ through $R_{n}^{T}$ have at least one nonzero entry is less than the number of rows itself. [...]

Why do the rows form a linearly dependent set based on the idea that "the number of columns for which the rows $R_{j}^{T}$ through $R_{n}^{T}$ have at least one nonzero entry is less than the number of rows itself."?

---

#### Appendix

Algorithm 3.12

[image: Description of Algorithm 3.12]

Comment: $k$ linearly independent vectors span a space of dimension $k$. Their span cannot be contained in a space of dimension $k - 1$ or less.

Comment: I think your question depends on what the author has already proven/shown. Also their definition of linear independence/dependence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof appears to be using the fact that linearly independent subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ have at most $n$ vectors in them. For the sake of illustration, let's say we're at step C with $j = 3$ in an $n \times n$ matrix. Then our matrix looks something like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & * & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & 1 & * & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}* & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}* & * & \cdots & * \\
\vdots & \vdots & \color{red}\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \color{red}* & * & \cdots & *
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The proof then tries to find the largest absolute value out of the red $\color{red}*$s, throwing an exception if every one is $0$. If every one of the $\color{red}*$s was $0$, then the last $n - 2$ rows each begins with three $0$s, and the $n - 2$ row vectors can be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^{n - 3}$ (by ignoring the first three $0$s). There are one too many such vectors for them to be linearly independent, hence the theorem (for the $j = 3$ case anyway; hopefully you can see how this would generalise).

Comment: I am starting to understand the proof better thanks to your answer. But, why $\Bbb{R}^{n - 3}$? Why ignore the first three $0$s, or, for a general case, the first $j$ entries?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais In my specific example, where $j = 3$, the first $3$ entries are all $0$, so we can embed them in $\Bbb{R}^3$, preserving linear independence, by simply ignoring the first $3$ entries. In general, it will be the first $j$ entries, embedding $n - j + 1$ vectors into $\Bbb{R}^{n-j}$. I only picked $j = 3$ so that I could illustrate what's happening.

Comment: "Why ignore the first three 0s" -- The span of a set of vectors is by definition the set of all linear combinations of those vectors. For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, suppose we have the vectors $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, 0)$. Can you see how all linear combinations of these vectors will never make the third coordinate anything other than zero? So, we say that these two vectors *span* a *subspace* of *dimension* 2. If you draw the picture in 3D, these two vectors span a "copy" of the $xy$-plane. It is all those vectors in 3D whose "height" is zero. Hopefully you can generalize to your example.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove the same statement for independent column vectors which is an equivalent statement.

If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent it is clear that $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$ and hence, the nullspace $N(A)$={$0$}.

That implies (since $dimN(A)+dim\Re(A)=n$) that $dim\Re(A)=n$ and hence every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be written as $Ay$. Therefore $e_{1}=Ay_{1},e_{2}=Ay_{2},...e_{n}=Ay_{n}$ which gives $AY=I$.

Also, $N(A)^{\perp}=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but $N(A)^{\perp}$=$\Re(A^{T})$ which gives that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be written as $A^{T}z$. Thus $e_{1}=A^{T}z_{1},e_{2}=A^{T}z_{2},...e_{n}=A^{T}z_{n}$

and hence $A^{T}Z=I$ i.e. $Z^{T}A=I$. Therefore $Z^{T}AY=Z^{T} \Rightarrow Y=Z^{T}$.

Thus there is an $Y$ such that $AY=YA=I$ which is the definition of the inverse of $A$. i.e. $A^{-1}=Y$. That completes the proof!!